# How can I refetch() my Query only when new subscription data arrives?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

Most examples use subscribeToMore within the query component but in my case the data returned by the query and subscription are very different so I think I need a discrete subscription component.

I have time series data being added to a database triggering `onChangedWeatherIntervals` subscription which returns summary info about the new time series info. If the new time series info matches the React client's filters it should request an updated histogram `getHistogram` query.

My test code:

```
<Query
  query={gql`
    {
      getHistogram (deviceID:"ARMS-NVM-P16", startTimestamp:1525201056) {
        columns {
          binWidth
          binHeight
          binCenter
        }
      }
     }
  `}
>
  {({
      loading: queryLoading,
      error: queryError,
      data: queryData,
      refetch
    }) => (
    <Subscription
      subscription={gql`
        subscription onChangedWeatherIntervals {
          onChangedWeatherIntervals {
            changedItems {
              deviceID
              timestamp
              siteKey
            }
          }
        }
      `}>
      {({
          data: subscriptionData,
          loading: subscriptionLoading,
          error: subscriptionError
        }) => {
        if (subscriptionData && !subscriptionLoading) {
          console.log("subscriptionData: ", subscriptionData);
          //TODO: Add code to inspect subscriptionData & determine if we refetch
          //refetch() //Uncommenting causes refetch loop after first server push
        }
        if (queryData && !queryLoading) {
          console.log("queryData: ", queryData.getHistogram.columns);
          return (<p>{queryData.getHistogram.columns[0].binWidth}</p>);
        }
        return null
      }}
    </Subscription>
  )
  }
</Query>
```

Because `subscriptionLoading` is `true` only before the first server push after mounting, I'm not sure the best way to distinguish re-renders from new subscriptionData. Should I store `subscriptionData` to `state.subscriptionData`  and compare the two on each render?

Is there a more elegant approach to all of this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried to use [subscribeToMore](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/subscriptions.html#subscribe-to-more) on your Query? You can probably call refetch in its updateQuery prop.

**UPDATE**: I happened to face the same problem in my app and figured out a way to solve it. Feel free to check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51487906/how-to-refetch-a-query-when-a-new-subscription-arrives-in-react-apollo#51505622). Basically you should avoid putting your subscription logic in a *render* method which will cause infinite refetch/re-rendering problem. The solution is to *move the logic out of render method and put it into a lifecycle method* like componentDidMount. That way subscribe won't be called again after a refetch is triggered.

Here's the code snippet for your case. (I used the hoc *graphql* from 'react-apollo' to help injecting query's *refetch* and *subscribeToMore* into props).

```
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';

class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { data: { refetch, subscribeToMore }} = this.props;

    this.unsubscribe = subscribeToMore({
      document: <ON_CHANGED_WEATHER_INTERVALS>,
      updateQuery: (prev) => {
        refetch();
        return prev;
      },     
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe();
  }

  render() {
    const { data: {queryData, loading, error } } = this.props;

    if (loading || error) return null;

    return <p>{queryData.getHistogram.columns[0].binWidth}</p>
  }
}

export default graphql(GET_HISTOGRAM, {
  options: {
    variables: {
      deviceID: 'ARMS-NVM-P16',
      startTimestamp:1525201056,
    },
  },
})(YourComponent)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Worked great for me using the refetch()!

Comment: @vemund glad it helps!