# How to refetch a query when a new subscription arrives in react-apollo

Tags: react-apollo

I was wondering if there's an elegant way to trigger the refetch of a query in react-apollo when a subscription receives new data (The data is not important here and will be the same as previous one). I just use subscription here as a notification trigger that tells Query to refetch.

I tried both using Subscription component and subscribeToMore to call "refetch" method in Query's child component but both methods cause infinite re-fetches.

NOTE: I'm using react-apollo v2.1.3 and apollo-client v2.3.5

here's the simplified version of code

```
<Query
  query={GET_QUERY}
  variables={{ blah: 'test' }}
>
  {({ data, refetch }) => (
    <CustomComponent data={data} />
    //put subscription here? It'll cause infinite re-rendering/refetch loop
  )}
<Query>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I figured it out myself with the inspiration from Pedro's answer.

**Thoughts:** the problem I'm facing is that I want to call Query's *refetch* method in Subscription, however, both Query and Subscription components can only be accessed in render method. That is the root cause of infinite refetch/re-rendering. To solve the problem, we need to move the subscription logic out of render method and put it somewhere in a lifecycle method (i.e. *componentDidMount*) where it won't be called again after a refetch is triggered. Then I decided to use *graphql* hoc instead of Query component so that I can inject props like *refetch*, *subscribeToMore* at the top level of my component, which makes them accessible from any life cycle methods.

**Code sample** (simplified version):

```
class CustomComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { data: { refetch, subscribeToMore }} = this.props;

    this.unsubscribe = subscribeToMore({
      document: <SUBSCRIBE_GRAPHQL>,
      variables: { test: 'blah' },
      updateQuery: (prev) => {
        refetch();
        return prev;
      },     
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe();
  }

  render() {
    const { data: queryResults, loading, error } } = this.props;

    if (loading || error) return null;

    return <WhatEverYouWant with={queryResults} />
  }
}

export default graphql(GET_QUERY)(CustomComponent);
```

Comment: Can you describe what is happening on that last `export default graphql(GET_QUERY)(CustomComponent);` line

Comment: @Jonathan Sure, graphql() creates a high-order component (HOC) that wraps the original CustomComponet and injects a couple props (e.g. data, loading, error, etc) into it. You can consider it as a shorthand for using <Query> component in render method in my original question. Here's the apollo's doc about how to use method graphql: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#graphql

Answer (score 2):

It's possible if you use `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` in the component rendered by the Subscription render props function.

The example uses `recompose` higher order components to avoid too much boilerplating. Would look something like:

```js
 /*
 * Component rendered when there's data from subscription
 */
export const SubscriptionHandler = compose(
  // This would be the query you want to refetch
  graphql(QUERY_GQL, { 
    name: 'queryName'
  }),
  lifecycle({

    refetchQuery() {
      // condition to refetch based on subscription data received
      if (this.props.data) {  
        this.props.queryName.refetch()
      }
    },

    componentDidMount() {
      this.refetchQuery();
    },

    componentDidUpdate() {
      this.refetchQuery();
    }
  })
)(UIComponent);


/*
 * Component that creates the subscription operation
 */
const Subscriber = ({ username }) => {
  return (
    <Subscription
      subscription={SUBSCRIPTION_GQL}
      variables={{ ...variables }}
    >
      {({ data, loading, error }) => {
        if (loading || error) {
          return null;
        }
        return <SubscriptionHandler data={data} />;
      }}
    </Subscription>
  );
});
```

Another way of accomplishing this while totally separating Query and Subscription components, avoiding loops on re-rendering is using Apollo [Automatic Cache updates](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html#automatic-updates):

```
                 +------------------------------------------+
                 |                                          |
    +----------->|  Apollo Store                            |
    |            |                                          |
    |            +------------------------------+-----------+
    +                                           |
client.query                                    |
    ^            +-----------------+  +---------v-----------+
    |            |                 |  |                     |
    |            | Subscription    |  | Query               |
    |            |                 |  |                     |
    |            |                 |  | +-----------------+ |
    |            |  renderNothing  |  | |                 | |
    +------------+                 |  | | Component       | |
                 |                 |  | |                 | |
                 |                 |  | +-----------------+ |
                 |                 |  |                     |
                 +-----------------+  +---------------------+
```

```js
const Component =() => (
  <div>
    <Subscriber />
    <QueryComponent />
  </div>
)

/*
 * Component that only renders Query data 
 * updated automatically on query cache updates thanks to 
 * apollo automatic cache updates
 */
const QueryComponent = graphql(QUERY_GQL, { 
  name: 'queryName'
})(() => {  
  return (
    <JSX />
  );
});

/*
 * Component that creates the subscription operation
 */
const Subscriber = ({ username }) => {
  return (
    <Subscription
      subscription={SUBSCRIPTION_GQL}
      variables={{ ...variables }}
    >
      {({ data, loading, error }) => {
        if (loading || error) {
          return null;
        }
        return <SubscriptionHandler data={data} />;
      }}
    </Subscription>
  );
});

/*
* Component rendered when there's data from subscription
*/
const SubscriptionHandler = compose(

  // This would be the query you want to refetch
  lifecycle({

    refetchQuery() {
      // condition to refetch based on subscription data received
      if (this.props.data) {  
        var variables = {
            ...this.props.data // if you need subscription data for the variables
        };

        // Fetch the query, will automatically update the cache
        // and cause QueryComponent re-render
        this.client.query(QUERY_GQL, {
          variables: {
            ...variables
          }
        });
      }
    },

    componentDidMount() {
      this.refetchQuery();
    },

    componentDidUpdate() {
      this.refetchQuery();
    }
  }),        
  renderNothing
)();


/*
* Component that creates the subscription operation
*/
const Subscriber = ({ username }) => {
    return (
        <Subscription
        subscription={SUBSCRIPTION_GQL}
        variables={{ ...variables }}
        >
        {({ data, loading, error }) => {
            if (loading || error) {
            return null;
            }
            return <SubscriptionHandler data={data} />;
        }}
        </Subscription>
    );
});
```

Note:
`compose` and `lifecycle` are [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md) methods that enable easier a cleaner higher order composition.

Comment: Thanks Pedro! I've updated my answer and provide a simplified code snippet. I think your suggestion is to wrap Query component into Subscription which will make the first rendering of UIComponent empty. Also, if the data received from subscription stays the same, I don't think SubscriptionHandler will update.

Comment: Do you still want it to update even if the subscription data is the same? You can still render `UIComponent` on Subscription `loading` or `error` states. For a more refined control on re-rendering, you will want to look at `networkStatus`.

Comment: yes, I want the component to re-render even subscription data is the same because refetched data can be different. I'm using subscription as a notification trigger, so it only notifies if there's new data. If there is, a refetch should be called to get new data. I posted an answer inspired by your answers. Thanks!